# During Javascript printing, the formatting not preserved

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to print an aspx page content. The page has several asp.net labels which display data. I am using javascript to print the page. It prints but the problem is the formatting is gone. For example, the first few rows of the page look like as shown below:

Field name       Old Value             New Value

Address1         1323 Bker street      5645 Lamar Road

In the preview and the printed page, the data are in six lines,  instead of the two shown above. Looks like that a new line character is introduced after each label.

```
function doPrint(s, e) {
        var prtContent = document.getElementById('PrintPanel');
        prtContent.border = 0; //set no border here
        var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=100,top=100,width=1000,height=1000,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,resizable=1');
        WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
    }
```

Comment: And your html that has the values?

Comment: Yes, my html has the values.

Comment: CSS Print Stylesheets! No need for pop up windows

Comment: Please let me know of any sample code for CSS Print Stylesheets. Thanks